# Using javascript-SDK for Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, share

I use javascript SDK for Facebook developer.
I am building a web with some comics adhered to a canvas.
Eventually I like the users share their own comics to Facebook

After I FB.init, I would like to check if the users have checked in Facebook
before they can share the comics. The following script corresponds to it.

`FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "comics", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.adropoflife.org");
    } 
    else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            postImageToFacebook(response.authResponse.accessToken, "comics", "image/png", decodedPng, "www.adropoflife.org");
        }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
    } 
}`

As the script suggests, I would like to make sure the users have logged in before `postImageToFacebook` runs. It turns out that `postImageToFacebook` runs before the logging process has finished and it leads to failure in share comics to Facebook. May anyone know how to circumvent this issue? Thanks!

Comment: you can´t call FB.login in the asynchronous callback function of FB.getLoginStatus, you have to call it on user interaction. read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: FYI: You are not allowed to specify the photo caption (I assume that is what you are using `"www.adropoflife.org"` for in your code) for the user, thje user has to type it in himself.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your webpage explains very clearly that the asynchronous callbacks have to be used carefully. I have a follow-up question. If I insist use only single button for a user to share the comics. What strategy can I use? Is it possible the wait until the FB.login has finished before postImageToFacebook is loaded?